# Restart or override Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two functions `autosubmit()` and `manualsubmit()`

```
function autosubmit() {
    $.post('action.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#container').html(data);
    });
}

function manualsubmit() {
    autosubmit();
}
```

`autosubmit()` is called on body load but sometime it takes time to `load` data in `container` then `manualsubmit()` is triggered by clicking try again button. I want to abort previous ajax request sent to server. I am unable to implement `abort()` method.

Comment: whats the problem with jquery abort()

Comment: i want to use $.post method

Comment: You can still use `abort()` with the result of `$.post`, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can i use it?? on jquery page it is used with $.ajax()

Comment: @reenleedr see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `$.post` does not preclude the use of `abort`. It returns a jqXHR object the same as `$.ajax` so you can call its abort method, something like this:

```
var previousRequest;

function autosubmit() {
    previousRequest = $.post('action.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#container').html(data);
    });
}

function manualsubmit() {
    previousRequest && previousRequest.abort(); // abort the request, if there was one
    autosubmit();
}
```

Note that this does not stop the AJAX request being made (as that is not possible), only the return handler for that request being executed.

Comment: is first line of manualsubmit() correct? i think it should be in if()

Comment: please explain `previousRequest && previousRequest.abort();`

Comment: That line first checks that the previousRequest variable is defined, and then calls `abort` on it.

Comment: one more doubt please. . if i assign `null` to previousRequest then what will this line be??

Comment: It would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cancel an ajax request once it's sent. You can only ignore the returned value in JS.

You can use `.data` to cancel showing the returned value:

```
function autosubmit(){
  $body = $("body");
  if($body.data('autosubmit') !== true){
    $.post('action.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data){
      if($body.data('autosubmit') !== true) $('#container').html(data);
    });
  }
}

function manualsubmit(){
  $("body").data('autosubmit',true);
  $.post('action.php', $('#form').serialize(), function(data){
    $('#container').html(data);
  });
}
```

Explanation: Once `manualsubmit()` is called, it adds `'autosubmit' => true` to the body of the document with jQuery's `.data`. If `autosubmit()` is called, or if its ajax request is returned, it makes sure the aforementioned value is absent before requesting or presenting the data.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this example:

```
var currentRequest = null;
currentRequest = $.ajax({
    url: 'action.php', 
    type: 'post', 
    data: {your_fields_params},  
    beforeSend: function(){
        if( currentRequest != null )
            currentRequest.abort();
    }, 
    success: function(){
    }
});
```